# how to install Socket.io over node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, web

I will need any help i can get to install socket.io over node.js for server.

I have already installed the node from the site. I am interested in step- by step(directory,e.t.c) as i am new to programming.
Thanks in advance
James

Comment: Have you tried this [tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)?

Comment: There are instructions for installing here: http://socket.io/docs/.  Please follow those instructions and if something doesn't work, ask a more specific question about exactly what you observe and exactly what doesn't work.  We don't produce tutorials here.  We can answer very specific questions about other tutorials.

Comment: @ Beterraba and jfriens00.Thanks and Yes.The site does not explain what to do with app.js and index.html files.There is no way to know when and where to use the command(window or node) in the site.Just codes without direction. I believe i have installed the "$ npm install socket.io" as i download the window installer msi.

Comment: @james [This screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l4gDD.png) shows what the directory that has the index.js and index.html looks like after trying the tutorial that Beterraba linked. If you get an error message that says: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile` then replace `sendFile` with `sendfile` (all lowercase). In Windows OS all the commands in the tutorial are run from the cmd.exe window and the chat messages are input from a web browser tab that is open at `http://localhost:3000`. If you install socket.io like the tutorial says it will install or reinstall it

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to install socket.io is with npm (Node Package Manager). npm is the default package manager for Node.js.The current Windows installer from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/)  will install npm along with Node.js. In Windows OS, open the cmd window and type:

```
npm install socket.io
```

This command will install socket.io in the local *node_modules* folder, which is owned by the current user.

npm can also take optional flags which are described at the [npm-install](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214093258/https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) webpage of [www.npmjs.org](http://www.npmjs.org).

In order to test if socket.io is working, try this tutorial: [Get Started: Chat application](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) which has been linked to by Beterraba in a comment below your question.